# Using javascript localstorage to store and load data?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, local-storage

I'm making a simple game in javascript and i'm interested in storing and loading the score with localstorage instead of it resetting after a refresh.

Current code:

```
var points = 0;   
if (
        hero.x <= (monster.x + 30)
        && monster.x <= (hero.x + 30)
        && hero.y <= (monster.y + 30)
        && monster.y <= (hero.y + 30)
    ) {
        ++points;
    }
```

My end result for storing the points should be something like this, but i can't quite figure it out:

```
if (
        hero.x <= (monster.x + 30)
        && monster.x <= (hero.x + 30)
        && hero.y <= (monster.y + 30)
        && monster.y <= (hero.y + 30)
   ) {
        localStorage.points=Number(localStorage.points)+1;
     }
else
     {
        localStorage.points=0;
     }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is: `localStorage.setItem("points", localStorage.getItem("points")+1);`

Comment: Using set/get methods is recommended over direct property access, but not required.